# Fiware Orion: how to delete entities based on attribute values

Tags: json, messagebroker, fiware-orion

I have a number of entities in Orion context broker such as the following one. The *user_id* attribute is used to distinguish entities generated by different users.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "id": "customCommands",
        "type": "Command",
        "servicePath": "/"
    },
    "attrNames": ["command", "user_id"],
    "attrs": {
        "command": {
            "type": "string",
            "creDate": 1455195329,
            "modDate": 1455195329,
            "value": "RASPBERRY_ID"
        },
        "user_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "creDate": 1455195329,
            "modDate": 1455195329,
            "value": "e260d1c6-f39e-4257-9f3e-91a82b281772"
        }
    },
    "creDate": 1455195329,
    "modDate": 1455195329
}
```

I would like to delete a number of such entities based on the value of the *user_id* attribute. I tried using filtering capabilities (*restriction* element) as follows to specify the users who want their entities removed. The json is posted to http://my_ip:my_port/v1/updateContext/ and I specified the following headers: *Accept: application/json* and *Content-Type: application/json*

```
{
    "contextElements": [{
        "type": "Command",
        "id": "customCommands"
    }],
    "restriction": {
        "scopes": [{
            "type": "FIWARE::StringQuery",
            "value": "user_id==e260d1c6-f39e-4257-9f3e-91a82b281772"
        }]
    },
    "updateAction": "DELETE"
}
```

However, I get the following error.

```
{
    "errorCode": {
        "code": "400",
        "reasonPhrase": "Bad Request",
        "details": "JSON Parse Error: unknown field: /restriction"
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or restrictions do not work to delete entities? If this is the case, how can I do it?

Comment: I bypassed the problem by moving _user\_id_ to the entity id using a separator as follows, and then removing based on the new id.

`{
    "_id": {
        "id": "customCommands|e260d1c6-f39e-4257-9f3e-91a82b281772",
        "type": "Command",
        "servicePath": "/"
    },
    "attrNames": ["command", "user_id"],
    "attrs": {
        "command": {
            "type": "string",
            "creDate": 1455195329,
            "modDate": 1455195329,
            "value": "RASPBERRY_ID"
        }
    },
    "creDate": 1455195329,
    "modDate": 1455195329
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `restriction` element can be used only in `queryContext`. Thus, using it in `updateContext` is not allowed and that explains the error message you are getting.

However, an easy workaround is working in two steps. First, you use `queryContext` with the `restriction` to get all the entities to delete. Then you can do an `updateContext` with all these entities and updateAction set to `DELETE`.